# Sympy returns log instead of ln

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, sympy, derivative

I have this equation:

```py
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol(‘x’, real = True)
fx = sp.log(x,3)

sp.diff(fx, x)
```

**Sympy returns:**

```
1/(x*log(3))
```

**Sympy should return:**

```
1/(x*ln(3))
```

Why is Sympy returning the log function rather than the natural log function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#exponentials-and-logarithms):

> ## Note:
>
> In SymPy, as in Python and most programming languages, log is the natural logarithm, also known as ln. SymPy automatically provides an alias ln = log in case you forget this.

```
>>> sp.ln(x)
log(x)
```

So the code you have posted is in fact, correct.

`sp.log(x,3)` is equivalent to `log(x)/log(3)`, and the derivative of this is `1/(x*log(3))` which in Sympy is equivalent to `1/(x*ln(3))`.

Comment: I wanted to add something for people who may be confused as to what this operation is called. This operation is called the change of base. That is, log_3(x) = ln(x)/ln(3) where log_3(x) is the log base 3 of x.